# How to add a link to django admin like the "add object" link?

Tags: django, django-admin

In django admin when you see a list of items for an object there is link at the top-right of the admin page which says "Add object".

How to add a similar link in django admin say "Add objects"?

Comment: What would "Add Objects" do? Do you want it to give you a form that can add multiple objects at once?

Comment: ya something like that. But what i'm stuck with is how to have that "Add Objects" beside the "Add Object" link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. solved by overriding the django admin templates.

Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) for more information.